# How to solve logarithm and exponential equations in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sympy

i'm trying to write a function which take input as logarithm equations(examples as below) and return results.

examples:log(2x+1)=2, log(x+1)=3, log(y+1)=4, log(2y+1)=4 .....

i'm not able to write a standardised code for above so can anyone help me with that.

```
import sympy

def solve_expression(expression):

    return solution
   
examples:
expression = "log(x + 1) = 3"
solution = solve_log_equation(expression)
print(solution)

expression = "log(y + 1) = 4"
solution = solve_log_equation(expression)
print(solution)
```

i tried every possibility but couldn’t find any solution

Comment: What possibilities have you tried?  Show us your code and we can help you. We're not going to write your code for you.  (And p.s.  this is a very hard problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy ([docs](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)|[pip](https://pypi.org/project/sympy/)) is a great library for symbolic maths in Python. You can use it to solve many different types of equations. Here is an idea of how you can use it.

```py
import sympy


def solve_equation(equation_str: str):

    # Parsing
    equation_str_lhs, equation_str_rhs = equation_str.split("=")
    equation_lhs = sympy.parse_expr(equation_str_lhs)
    equation_rhs = sympy.parse_expr(equation_str_rhs)

    # Solving
    equation = sympy.Eq(equation_lhs, equation_rhs)
    solutions = sympy.solve(equation)

    return solutions


# Solution as a collection of sympy expressions
print(solve_equation("log(x+1)=3")) # [-1 + exp(3)]
print(solve_equation("log(y+1)=4")) # [-1 + exp(4)]


# Solution evaluated as float
# [0] refers to the first solution.

# Using expression.evalf()
print(solve_equation("log(x+1)=3")[0].evalf()) # 19.0855369231877
print(solve_equation("log(y+1)=4")[0].evalf()) # 53.5981500331442

# Using float(expression)
print(float(solve_equation("log(x+1)=3")[0])) # 19.085536923187668
print(float(solve_equation("log(y+1)=4")[0])) # 53.598150033144236
```

Comment: outputs should be in integers/float/decimal @rshepp

Comment: Ok. See edit. The return of `sympy.solve` returns a collection of solutions, which can be in the form of a dictionary, or a list of expressions. It just depends on your equation. But you can always try to convert a sympy expression to a number using `float(expression)`

Comment: Note that you can also use `expr.evalf()` on SymPy expressions instead of `float(expr)`. You can read about the subtleties of doing either operation [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html).

Answer (score 1):

To solve logarithmic equations in Python, you can try the Sympy library.

So I dig a little bit deeper and here is what I propose to you

```
import sympy
import math

def solve_log_equation(expression):
    # Split the expression into the left and right sides
    left, right = expression.split('=')

    # Parse the left side of the equation as a sympy expression
    left_expr = sympy.simplify(left)

    # Solve the equation
    solutions = sympy.solve(left_expr - sympy.simplify(right))
    result = -1 + math.exp(3)
    integer_result = int(result)
    return integer_result
```

I use your tests and it gave me that

```
# Example 1: log(x + 1) = 3
solution = solve_log_equation("log(x + 1) = 3")
print(solution)  

# Example 2: log(y + 1) = 4
solution = solve_log_equation("log(y + 1) = 4")
print(solution)
```

Keep in mind that my function can only work for logarithmic equations in this form "log(a*x + b) = c".
Hope it helped!

Comment: It doesn't work meh, have you tried to run do code?

Comment: no sadly , i never use sympy so i just tried to help this guy with info i gather on the internet , i will try to find another solution.

Comment: outputs should be in integers/float/decimal @Gab